# Was Sherlock pretending when identifying the corpse?

Tags: plot-explanation, sherlock

When *Sherlock* was to identify the dead body of Irene Adler in "A Scandal in Belgravia", did he really think it's hers or did he pretend to fool everyone else as he suspected Irene did that on purpose?

Comment: Seems logical, but then again, he could have pretended that well.

Comment: @JoanaJanicka Considering the fact that Sherlock is a sociopath, he easily could've. but it constantly shows that Sherlock has some kind of real affection towards Adler. As Paulie_D mentioned in his answer, Sherlock's concern about Adler wasn't pretended.

Comment: I believe so. Although I am sure it was not love.

Comment: It's a high probability that Sherlock may never see **Love** as ordinary *boring* people see, or feel. but the primary,basic feeling is the same. The way I see it is, that Sherlock have a big affection that he only had about John Watson (Obviously in a different way) before. He admires Adler while having huge attraction and affection deep inside him. You can categorize what it is as something, but for Sherlock, it's not ordinary.

Answer (score 8):

All the indications are that Sherlock truly believed she was dead.

Certainly he acts like he believes it..John says...

> JOHN: He’s writing sad music; doesn’t eat; barely talks – only to correct the television.
>
> (He walks further into the room and finally a figure begins to step out of the shadows at the other end.)
>
> JOHN: I’d say he was heartbroken but, er, well, he’s Sherlock.
>
> <sup>[**Source**](https://arianedevere.livejournal.com/26848.html#cutid1)</sup>

All the evidence would seem to confirm it...including DNA which was faked.

We see Sherlock receive the text from Irene and leave the abandoned building and in the very next scene clearly shows him as disoriented and somewhat *lost in thought*.

**In short, there is NO evidence that Sherlock knew Irene was alive until she texted him to say so and it seems to have knocked him for a loop to find out.**